# Rewrite subdir / query param to root / query param

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect mysite.com/all-tags?tag=[tag] to mysite/[tag]

In htaccess, I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tag=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/all-tags$ /%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

RewriteEngine is on, and existing FURL rules are:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This doesn't function properly. Anyone have insight as to where this is incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `example.com/tag/[tag]` instead of `example.com/[tag]` as you already have a front controller `index.php` handling all non-files, non-directories:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /all-tags?\?tag=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tag/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^tag/(.+)$ all-tags?tag=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks - this works on the production server, not on localhost (which is fine). One question - the tags in use are capitalized, which translates to URIs like mydomain.com/[Tag] rather than mydomain.com/[tag]). I know of general Apache rules for forcing lowercase, and could also refactor tags if needed, but can the force-lowercase rule be constrained to this ruleset?

Comment: Converting URLs to lowercase will require Aapche config change for declaring a `RewriteMap`. Do you have access to Apache config files?

Comment: I do - but think it doesn't make sense to have the server handle this processing when refactoring is possible. Thanks for your assistance!